# Is there a graph of ethereum transaction fees?

Tags: mining, blockchain, statistics

I am looking for statistics of how much Ethereum miners make on transactions fees, is there some kind of statistic on this?

Answer (score 6):

I just created a [chart that shows how much fees are ever earned daily by miners](https://neurone.github.io/ethereum/stats.htm).

If you want to do it by yourself, it can be calculated with a client (i.e. geth), listing all transactions ever mint and verifying gasPrice and gasUsed.

A list of *funny* facts I discoverd during the creation of this chart.

- The three top most expensive transactions are:

  - [2015/08/08 15:44:00](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x9c81f44c29ff0226f835cd0a8a2f2a7eca6db52a711f8211b566fd15d3e0e8d4) - **14.36963** - Creation of the Ethereum Foundation's multisig account
  - [2016/06/21 18:18:06](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x0036551e131382d3c8be08c3c7600fd42958c6da3774cde9e44017e30ade56df) - **13.50000** - WhiteHatDAOContractController operation (**throwed exception... ^^**)
  - [2016/05/28 08:56:25](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xd3cc009c63ad0a2d50c3204623df8d0c8eb2775e05fc3fe1c8e9253138607279) - **10.70863** - Gatecoin calling TheDAO
- A grand total of 8 transactions didn't paid for fees at all:

  - [10/02/2016 09:55:01](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x5d38479cf8a4aba60e20c661c60ad146a2cb4d5b94f246ed0273d4a4b3ef4835)
  - [11/02/2016 16:48:00](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x922894ba3b24100547e09c37930fadf00302aa316e0acb488844cbbfb18bdc68)
  - [06/03/2016 14:30:25](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc7402cef7daadc193f6f3c18ff7c732a657279e8fbe58a4c14b695aad47f959)
  - [22/08/2016 05:39:53](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xc3fa8399ef7922aef0ec7278f7b4b5e28e7191eba3027ca1143af2cf17acae86)
  - [22/08/2016 05:39:53](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xaab5e7279750d3f9ba796356ad770aa0004fa6f3264f456d1e0c8ad83c650112)
  - [22/08/2016 05:39:53](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xc6d3bc398a2fbe62dc0872afe81db2e4c4c182c275361aed7e7297731e285e49)
  - [30/08/2016 03:46:30](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x2147bbdbc66d751623b969cef811b0e9c0acee9eb2eb3411347fb100ded77a82)
  - [30/08/2016 03:46:30](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x3be99e938967c2678027a675b411594189650137b47896392fc41c8e471ceb25)

Side note: Ethereum is the platform, the name of the coin is Ether (ETH for friends).

Answer (score 1):

[Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io) has a page dedicate to transaction data, including [a graph of the average transaction fees](https://amberdata.io/dashboards/transactions?highlight=11):

[image]

And for those interested in APIs (as I am) you can even get current average gas prices with their [gas predictions endpoint](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference#get-gas-predictions)!